# Explicit cast in C

Tags: c++, c, alignment, type-conversion, casting

I want to convert pointers of any type to *int* in C and C++. The code must be the same for both C and C++. The following program works for C but not for C++.

```
int main(void)
{
    long long a;
    int b = (int)&a;

    return 0;
}
```

How can I get it working for C++?

Comment: C++ is backwards compatible with C so anything that works in C works in C++.

Comment: It does not compile with g++. Should I have said, it should work with gcc and g++?

Comment: @heavyd: Not true.

Comment: Your edited code works fine for me on VC++, gcc and g++.

Comment: It doesn't compile and it doesn't give an error message -- weird :)

Comment: You can't do this portably as a pointer may be a larger data type (i.e. more bits) than an `int`.

Comment: @Tony: The result may not be correct, but you can still *do it* and it will compile on all compilers -- the OP's complaint was that it doesn't compile.

Comment: @Lou - I HATE it when compilers do that.

Comment: @casablanca: depends if you mean convert in the common English sense (implying some logical equivalence pre/post) or in a C++ Standardese sense...

Comment: It amazes me that people can vote "[the question] cannot be reasonably answered in its current form." on questions *that have up-voted answers...*

Comment: This code is (1) wrong (you cannot store pointers in `int`) and (2) a complete no-op. Any reasonable compiler will compile it to no code whatsoever.

Comment: It is not good to edit a question such that you render the very answer you accepted inapplicable. -1 and vote to close.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looks like you want the `offsetof` macro, it's defined in `<stddef.h>`.

Edit: You have changed your example, now you should look at `intptr_t` or `uintptr_t` which are in `stdint.h`.  Do not, under any circumstances, put an address into a plain `int`.

Comment: Is it portable and is it supported by all compilers?

Comment: But I want to put it into an _int_, thats the point. Anyway, intptr_t does not allow me to put a long long* into it.

Comment: Yes, `offsetof` is specified by C89 and C++98 (and all later revisions).

Comment: It doesn't fit in an `int` so you can't have that.  Show us what you actually want to do with it.

Comment: Well you answered my question when you told me about offsetof. I want to use the offset in an expression that is supposed to be an integral constant expression. Thanks!

Comment: BTW, I think you misunderstand `intptr_t`.  It is a signed integer type capable of holding an address (of any type).  "The following  type  designates  a signed integer type with the property that any valid pointer to `void` can be converted to this type, then converted back to a pointer to `void`, and the result will compare equal to the original pointer: `intptr_t`"

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean:

```
struct X
{
        char a;
        long long b;
};

int main(void)
{
        int b[20];
        // C++ requires fixed size of arrays.

        b[(int)(&((struct X*)0)->b) - 8] = 5;
        // This will compile But what you get is not even worth guessing at.

        return 0;
}
```

Comment: This is fine too as long as there is a conversion from a pointer to _int_. But I did mean it for the program I have written.

Comment: @user95281: You changed your code so its hard to know that. Even if there is not a valid conversion your new code will compile. If the pointer is 64 bit and the int is 32 bit it still compiles fine.